# WebVR not working with latest version of Firefox

Tags: javascript, webvr, steamvr, webxr

I've been experiencing an issue when using the VR functionality of a WebVR project in the recent versions of Firefox. Usually less than a minute after starting VR, SteamVR will begin to flash between responsive and unresponsive while the framerate tanks. Restarting SteamVR and reloading the project will sometimes fix the issue, other times SteamVR will need to be reinstalled completely. Even then the problem will return in the same manner as before, rendering the VR functionality unusable.

I noticed that an older version of Firefox from June 2018, [particularly this one here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/60.2.0esr/win64/en-US/,), does not have this same issue and will run VR without an issue. Was there some change in the WebVR API?

I created a release for [my project here](https://github.com/mtwoodard/hypVR-Ray/releases/tag/WebVRError), and you can find a [live version here.](http://www.michaelwoodard.net/hypVR-Ray/) In order to use the VR capabilities first click the VR icon then press the 'v' key to enter and exit tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're running into this recent Firefox bug:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1514417 - "WebVR framerate drops to < 1 FPS after several minutes, requires full restart"

The bug has been fixed in the latest Firefox Nightly: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/#nightly

Comment: Interesting... I also remember experiencing this same bug in Chrome Canary, although I don't remember if I had a fresh install of SteamVR to run. Have you experimented with any other browsers?

Comment: Nope, I haven't been using Chrome very much. 
Also, an update: It looks like the Firefox bug fix will be released in the next Firefox Beta as well